# Toyota Yaris 2015 rattling noise in 1st and rev gears

Tags: toyota, noise, manual-transmission, yaris, rattle

I ve got a Toyota yaris 2015 1.33 hatchback model. There is a rattling noise when I just start to move my car in 1st or reverse gear. There is no rattling noise when the car is idle, but only when I start to pull away. It stops after I attain a certain speed like above 10 or 15 mph. Any Ideas? . And it happens only after calm acceleration

According to my observations,

1. Rapid vehicle acceleration in just after start or any other time, no noise
2. Idling just after start or any other time, no noise
3. Idling and throttling in neutral or parking position, no noise
4. higher speeds and rpm, no noise
5. noise comes only after calm acceleration just after start and for few seconds 
   and after a few hundred yards, it goes away.

I would highly appreciate any help. This has been going on for quite some time now. I did a full service but the mechanics were unable to find a solution.

Comment: Is this automatic transmission Yaris?

Comment: Hi juhist, it's manual

Comment: Ok, then you could try carefully accelerating in 2nd gear from standstill, just to see if this affects the 2nd gear too. Don't burn the clutch though! Might be easiest on a very slight downhill.

Comment: I tried accelerating in 2nd gear and the sound is there. It doesn't happen all the time, sometimes you have to make a small turn. It's quite difficult to reproduce the sound but when it happens it's quite loud.